# What do Steen and Seebach mean when discussing limit points of sequences in Particular Point Topology

Tags: general-topology

In "Counterexamples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach (2ed: 1978), they are discussing the Particular Point Topology, which they define as:

"On any set $X$, we can define the open sets of a topology to be $\varnothing$ and any subset of $X$ that contains a particular point $p$. We distinguish three cases, finite, countable, and uncountable according to the size of $X$."

(It is of course assumed that $p \in X$.)

Their first article goes:

1. The sequences $\langle a_i \rangle$ which converge are those for which the $a_i \ne p$ are equal for all but a finite number of indices. The only accumulation points for sequences are the points $b_j$ that the $a_i$ equal for infinitely many indices. So any countably infinite set containing $p$ has a limit point, but never an accumulation point when considered as a sequence in any ordering.

This is how S&S define an accumulation point of a sequence:

"... every open set containing $p$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence. In this case $p$ is called an **accumulation point of the sequence**."

That is, an accumulation point $\alpha$ is such that:

$\forall U \in \tau: x \in U \implies \{n \in \mathbb N: x_n \in U\}$ is infinite (where $\tau$ is the topology in question).

My understanding (or lack of it) is as follows.

By definition, a sequence converges to $\alpha$ iff there exist only a finite number of open sets containing $\alpha$ which do not contain any given term of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

But consider the sequence $\langle a_i \rangle = \left\langle{\dfrac 1 i}\right\rangle_{i \in \mathbb N}$ in the particular point space $(\mathbb R, \tau_p)$ where $p = 1$ and $\mathbb R$ denotes the reals.

$\langle a_i \rangle$ converges to $0$, which does not equal $1$, but none of the $a_i$ are equal. All of the sets of $(\mathbb R, \tau_p)$ of the form $\left[{0, \dfrac 1 n}\right] \cup \{1\}$ are open in the particular point topology, so I don't understand that first sentence of article $1$.

Hence there seems to be a convergent sequence for which $a_i \ne p$ are *not* equal for all but a finite number of indices. And so the sentence about accumulation points is equally questionable.

As for the rest of the article, I can't get my head round it until I resolve my problem with these first bits.

Any insight appreciated, and a full explanation of the whole will be greatly appreciated and gratefully received.

Comment: Your sequence does not converge to $0$: $\{0\}\cup\{p\}$ is an open set around $0$ containing no $a_i$

Comment: Hmm. I fear I'm going to need a fuller answer than that, because I don't understand this enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the definition of convergence

> By definition, a sequence converges to $\alpha$ iff there exist only a finite number of open sets containing $\alpha$ which do not contain any given term of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

**No** It's actually more similar to the definition of acumulation point that you gave :

$$\forall U \in \tau: \alpha \in U \implies \{n \in \Bbb N: x_n \in U\} \text{ only misses finitely many points of } \Bbb N$$

So all open neighbourhoods of the limit contain "almost all" (at most finitely many exceptions allowed) terms of the sequence.

So your sequence does not converge to $0$ in $\tau_p$: $\{0,p\}$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ that contains *at most two* terms of the sequence (as the sequence has all distinct terms).

The sequence $0,1,0,1, \ldots$ has at least accumulation points $0$ and $1$ (in any topology) and in $\tau_p ( p=1) $ it doesn't have any other, and no limit. This is in accordance with Steen and Seebach's statement.

Comment: I'm going to have to go away and sleep on it. Thanks. With that explanation in mind, I will try to see how to get to an understanding of that first sentence in the article.

Comment: @PrimeMover Ponder on it some more. It's a simple enough topology to completely classify all sequences with accumulation points and limits. It's only of didactical interest; let it teach you..

Comment: Okay, fair enough, that told me. I'm getting old.

Comment: This is still giving me a problem though: "The only accumulation points for sequences are the points $b_j$ that the $a_i$ equal for infinitely many indices." 1. If the seq. does not converge, there could be many such points. 2: if the seq. converges to $p$ then *all" points $b$ in $S$ are accumulation points for the sequence, as $\{b, p\}$ is a subset of all open sets containing $b$ and contain infinite points in that sequence.

Comment: If $a_n \to p$ (I assume $p$ is still the special point) then, as $\{p\}$ is open, almost all $a_n =p$ and if then for any $b \neq p$ indeed $\{b,p\}$ is the minimal open neighbourhood of $b$ and it contains almost all (so certainly infinitely many) terms. So *all* points of $X$ are limits of the sequence, not "merely" accumulation points. Goes to show how non-unique a limit can be.

Comment: Yes, but how is that consistent with "The only accumulation points for sequences are the points $b_j$ that the $a_i$ equal for infinitely many indices." We've just said that *all* points in $S$ are accumulation points of such a sequence. As I say, I'm sorry but I *don't understand what's being driven at* and just "thinking about it" does not help. I want to get past this and move on.

Comment: @PrimeMover They are working in the context where all $a_n \neq p$. If then $b$ is an accumulation point, this means that $\{n: a_n \in \{b,p\}\}$ is infinite (and *in this context*) this is just $\{n: a_n = b\}$, provided $b \neq p$. So the accumulation points of such a sequence is any 'non-special" point that occurs infinitely many times.

Comment: Oh okay, that was not clear. It just says "The only accumulation points for sequences ..." and does not say anything about that context. Would it be fair to consider that omission a mistake?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi.  I am not sure the last paragraph is correct, regarding the sequence $0,1,0,1,\dots$.  I have added a detailed answer and would appreciate if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt to answer my own question, which is "make sense of that first sentence of the quoted passage."

Let $\langle a_i \rangle$ be a convergent sequence in a particular point space $T = (S, \tau_p)$, where $p$ is the particular point and $\tau$ is the set of all subsets of $S$ which contain $p$.

Let $\langle a_i \rangle$ converge to $\alpha$.

By definition of convergent sequence, all open sets of $T$ contain all but finitely many terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

This includes $\{\alpha, p\}$.

So all but a finite number of terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$ is equal either to $\alpha$ or $p$.

Hence all but a finite number of terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$ such that $a_i \ne p$ is equal to $\alpha$.

Job done.

Comment: That's sentence one done. Next?

Comment: Hi Prime Mover.  I think there are a few things in this answer that are not quite correct. (and I also agree with you that the first item in the particular point topology in Steen & Seebach is confusing and not quite correctly expressed). I have added a more detailed answer that I hope answers everything.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give a full overview of convergence of sequences and accumulation points of sequences in $X$ with the particular point topology (with $p\in X$ as the "particular point").  So let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence in $X$.

#### Limits of sequences

By definition, $(a_n)_n$ converges to a point $a$ if every nbhd of $a$ contains all $a_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.  In the case that there is a smallest nbhd $V$ of $a$ (which is the case for each point in the particular space topology), it is equivalent to require that all $a_n$ belong to $V$ for large enough $n$.  For $a=p$, that smallest nbhd is $\{p\}$.  For $a\ne p$, that smallest nbhd is $\{a,p\}$.  So we get:

1. $(a_n)_n$ converges to $p$ exactly when $a_n=p$ for all sufficiently large $n$ (the sequence is eventually constant equal to $p$).
2. $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a\ne p$ exactly when $a_n\in\{a,p\}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

#### Accumulation points of sequences

By definition, the point $a\in X$ is an [accumulation point of the sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#For_sequences_and_nets) $(a_n)_n$ if every nbhd of $a$ contains $a_n$ for infinitely many indices $n$.  Similar to limits, it is enough to require this for the smallest nbhd of $a$ in the topology of $X$.  We get:

1. $p$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_n$ exactly when $p$ occurs infinitely many times in the sequence.
2. $a\ne p$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_n$ exactly when $a$ occurs infinitely many times in the sequence or $p$ occurs infinitely many times in the sequence.

In particular, if $p$ occurs infinitely many times, every point of $X$ is an accumulation point of the sequence.

#### Examples

(taking $a$, $b$ distinct points, both different from $p$)

- The sequence $(p,p,p,\dots)$ converges to all points of $X$.  All the points of $X$ are accumulation points of the sequence.
- The sequence $(a,a,a,\dots)$ converges to $a$ only, and $a$ is its only accumulation point.
- The sequence $(a,p,a,p,a,p,\dots)$ converges to $a$ only.  All the points of $X$ are accumulation points of the sequence.
- The sequence $(a,b,p,a,b,p,a,b,p,\dots)$ does not converge.  All the points of $X$ are accumulation points of the sequence.
- The sequence $(a,b,a,b,a,b,\dots)$ does not converge.  Its accumulation points are $a$ and $b$.