# Accumulation Points of Sequence in Particular Point Space

Tags: general-topology

Returning to "Counterexamples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach (2ed: 1978), in their discussion of the Particular Point Topology, which they define as:

"On any set $X$, we can define the open sets of a topology to be $\varnothing$ and any subset of $X$ that contains a particular point $p$. We distinguish three cases, finite, countable, and uncountable according to the size of $X$."

This question is a continuation of my pondering this question which I asked earlier and remains unresolved:

[What do Steen and Seebach mean when discussing limit points of sequences in Particular Point Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689210/what-do-steen-and-seebach-mean-when-discussing-limit-points-of-sequences-in-part)

I need to make sure I understand this:

Let $T = (S, \tau_p)$ be a particular point space on $S$ such that $\tau_p$ is the set of all subsets of $S$ which contain $p$.

Let $\langle a_i \rangle$ be a sequence in $T$.

Let $\langle a_i \rangle$ converge to $p$.

Then *every* point in $T$ not equal to $p$ is an accumulation point of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

By thinking behind this is:

Because $\langle a_i \rangle$ converges to $p$, an infinite number of terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$ are equal to $p$.

Let $\beta \in S$ be arbitrary, but such that $\beta \ne p$.

Let $U \in \tau_p$ contain $\beta$.

Then $U$ also contains $p$.

That means $U$ also contains an infinite number of terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

So every $U \in \tau_p$ containing $\beta \in S$ contains an infinite number of terms of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

Hence by definition $\beta$ is an accumulation point of $\langle a_i \rangle$.

Is this correct or have I misled myself somewhere here?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\tau_p$, then several things could happen (assume that in case $i$ we have that cases $j < i$ do not occur anymore):

1. For some $q \in X$, $N(q):= \{n: a_n = q\}$ is cofinite. If $q\neq p$ this means that $a_n \to q$ and any other point $r\neq q$ has a neighbourhood $\{r,p\}$ which contains at most finitely many terms of the sequence, so no other point is accumulation point of $(a_n)_n$, let alone limit. If $q=p$, however, $a_n \to r$ for any $r \in X$, as any neighbourhood of $r$ contains $p$ by definition, and this occurs cofinitely often.
2. $N(p)$ is infinite, but not cofinite. Then any $x \in X$ is accumulation point of $(a_n)_n$, as is clear from the definition, but the sequence can only *converge* to a (unique, in that case) point $q \neq p$ that obeys that $N(p) \cup N(q)$ is cofinite.
3. If $N(q)$ is infinite for some $q \neq p$, then clearly such a $q$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_n$. There can be at most countably many of such accumulation points, and none of them can be a limit.
4. If all $N(x)$ are finite (the final case), then the sequence has no accumulation point and a fortioti no limit either.